# Moving SVG path through points

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, path

it might seem weird but i would like to move some SVG path through a fixed point. I get how we can animate a dot through a path with `<animateMotion>` and I'm trying to get the same result but the dot would be fixed and the path would move through it.

So far, I thought I could work with `path.getTotalLength()`, I made a loop to create dots on my path and I wanted to animate my path to be centered on each dot but my knowledge on SVG and Javascript is pretty limited.

```js
const path = document.getElementById('chemin')
let svg = document.getElementById("mySVG");
let totalLength = path.getTotalLength();
let intersections = 30;

for (var i = 0; i <= intersections; i++) {
    let distance = i * 1 / intersections * totalLength;
    let point = path.getPointAtLength(distance);
    addCircleToSVG(point.x, point.y);
}

function addCircleToSVG(x, y) {
    let circle = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'circle');
    circle.setAttribute("cx", x);
    circle.setAttribute("cy", y);
    circle.setAttribute("r", "5");
    circle.setAttribute("fill", "#8888ff");
    svg.appendChild(circle);
}
```

```html
<div class="svgDiv">
    <svg version="1.1" id="mySVG" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1306 989" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1306 989;" xml:space="preserve">
        <style type="text/css">
            .st1 {
                fill: #fff;
                stroke: #000000;
                stroke-width: 3;
                stroke-miterlimit: 10;
            }

            .st2 {
                fill: none;
                stroke: #ff0000;
                stroke-width: 8;
                stroke-miterlimit: 10;
                stroke-linecap: round;
            }
        </style>
        <g>
            <path id="chemin" class="st2" d="M315,443l13-11h13l13-2h9l7.5,1.5h10l8-4l4-5l15,5l10,4h12h16l16-2l4-1h11h9l8-6h6l8-2l5-3l4-2l5-4l3-3v-4l4-3
                    l5-1h11c0,0,0,0,2,0s12,0,12,0l6,3l3,4l4,4l6,2c0,0,1,0,3-1s6-3,6-3l3-2l5,1h6l8,3l8,1c0,0,4,1,5,1s9,0,9,0l7,1h9h5l6-2l4-1l4-3
                    l5-2l6-4l4-5l4-4l2-5c0,0,1-2,1-4s0-5,0-5v-4c0,0,4,3,4,3l7,2l5,3l6,1l11,2l8,2l7,5l10,2c3-3,6-5,6-5l4-3l4-2l4,2l4-1l-2-6l5-5
                    c0,0,8,3,8,0s4-6,4-6l6-4l3-4l6-6c0,0,0-3-2-7s-5-8-5-8s-2-5-3-9s-4-9-4-11s2-6,1-8s-5-7-5-7v-8l-1-7v-5l-8-11">
            </path>
        </g>
    </svg>

</div>
```

It seemed like an idea at first but now I feel like it won't get me anywhere and I'm stuck...

EDIT:
A picture might make this more understandable,
[that's the "steps" I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTcLu.png)

Comment: Have the svg centered? Or the line in relation to each dot? So like the line appears to animate to each dot before the dot is added (like an Indiana Jones map style? Or [like this](http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/examples/path.html) with dots?) yea sorry I'm still not sure I'm visualizing the intent, will revisit later though for fun, heading out soon. :D

Comment: I added a picture to show what i'm trying to do, it might help ^^' The dot is always centered and the path move through it and following it's own path...
No problem, thank you !

Comment: You want to highlight each point one by one and at that moment translate the path to that point coords?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main idea is that I'm changing the value of the viewBox attribute of the svg element while I'm changing the postion of the circle on the path. This is **giving the illusion** that the path is moving not the dot.

I'm using an input type range to move the circle.

The `start` variable represents the point where the path is starting (`d="M315,443...`) and also the initial position of the dot: `<circle cx="315" cy="443"`.

Please read the comments in the code.

```js
let lengthChemin = chemin.getTotalLength();
// the starting point of the circle on the path
let start={x:315,y:443}

//while moving the thumb of the slider
control.addEventListener("input", ()=>{
  // get the actual value of the input
  let val = parseInt(control.value);
  //get the new position of the circle on the path
  let pos = chemin.getPointAtLength(lengthChemin*val/100);
  //update the circle's position
  updateElement({cx:pos.x, cy:pos.y}, circle)
  //update the viewBox value
  theSVG.setAttribute("viewBox",`${pos.x - start.x} ${pos.y - start.y} 1306 600`)
})


function updateElement(o, element) {
  for (var name in o) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      element.setAttributeNS(null, name, o[name]);
    }
  }
  return element;
}
```

```html
<input id="control" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" />

<svg id="theSVG" viewBox="0 0 1306 600">

  <g transform="translate(0,-250)">
    <path id="chemin" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" fill="none"  d="M315,443l13-11h13l13-2h9l7.5,1.5h10l8-4l4-5l15,5l10,4h12h16l16-2l4-1h11h9l8-6h6l8-2l5-3l4-2l5-4l3-3v-4l4-3
                    l5-1h11c0,0,0,0,2,0s12,0,12,0l6,3l3,4l4,4l6,2c0,0,1,0,3-1s6-3,6-3l3-2l5,1h6l8,3l8,1c0,0,4,1,5,1s9,0,9,0l7,1h9h5l6-2l4-1l4-3
                    l5-2l6-4l4-5l4-4l2-5c0,0,1-2,1-4s0-5,0-5v-4c0,0,4,3,4,3l7,2l5,3l6,1l11,2l8,2l7,5l10,2c3-3,6-5,6-5l4-3l4-2l4,2l4-1l-2-6l5-5
                    c0,0,8,3,8,0s4-6,4-6l6-4l3-4l6-6c0,0,0-3-2-7s-5-8-5-8s-2-5-3-9s-4-9-4-11s2-6,1-8s-5-7-5-7v-8l-1-7v-5l-8-11">
    </path>
    
    <circle id="circle" cx="315" cy="443" r="10"/>
  </g>
  
  
</svg>
```

> Observation: I'm translating the group with the path and the circle ONLY because I want it to be visible when you run the snippet. You can remove this.

Comment: That is exactly what I had in mind, thank you so much ! So if I understand well, changing the value of the viewBox will make every other elements (I have some more squares and dots) move the same way as the path, right ? (just to be sure, that's actually what I want)

Comment: Basically yes but everything deppend on what you have. If things are not going as you expect please ask a different question with all the details. I would be glad to help.

Comment: Note: if you set the default [pathLength (see MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/pathLength) to **100**, you probably don't need any input calculations

Answer (score 2):

```js
const path = document.getElementById('chemin')
const svg = document.getElementById("mySVG");
const rect = svg.getAttribute('viewBox').split(' ');

const cx = rect[2]/2;
const cy = rect[3]/5; // Should be /2 (to not be out of small view field here)

const circle = svg.querySelector('circle');
circle.setAttribute('cx', cx);
circle.setAttribute('cy', cy);

const intersections = 30;
const timeStep = 500;

const points = [];

for(let i=0; i <= intersections; i++){
    points.push(path.getPointAtLength((path.getTotalLength()/intersections)*i));
}

points.forEach((p,i) => {
    setTimeout(() => {movePath(p)}, timeStep*i);
})

function movePath(point){
    path.setAttribute('transform', `translate(${cx-point.x}, ${cy-point.y})`);
}
```

```html
<div class="svgDiv">
    <svg version="1.1" id="mySVG" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1306 989" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1306 989;" xml:space="preserve">
        <style type="text/css">
            .st1 {
                fill: #fff;
                stroke: #000000;
                stroke-width: 3;
                stroke-miterlimit: 10;
            }

            .st2 {
                fill: none;
                stroke: #ff0000;
                stroke-width: 8;
                stroke-miterlimit: 10;
                stroke-linecap: round;
            }
        </style>
        <g>
            <path id="chemin" class="st2" d="M315,443l13-11h13l13-2h9l7.5,1.5h10l8-4l4-5l15,5l10,4h12h16l16-2l4-1h11h9l8-6h6l8-2l5-3l4-2l5-4l3-3v-4l4-3
                    l5-1h11c0,0,0,0,2,0s12,0,12,0l6,3l3,4l4,4l6,2c0,0,1,0,3-1s6-3,6-3l3-2l5,1h6l8,3l8,1c0,0,4,1,5,1s9,0,9,0l7,1h9h5l6-2l4-1l4-3
                    l5-2l6-4l4-5l4-4l2-5c0,0,1-2,1-4s0-5,0-5v-4c0,0,4,3,4,3l7,2l5,3l6,1l11,2l8,2l7,5l10,2c3-3,6-5,6-5l4-3l4-2l4,2l4-1l-2-6l5-5
                    c0,0,8,3,8,0s4-6,4-6l6-4l3-4l6-6c0,0,0-3-2-7s-5-8-5-8s-2-5-3-9s-4-9-4-11s2-6,1-8s-5-7-5-7v-8l-1-7v-5l-8-11">
            </path>
        </g>
        <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="5" fill="#8888ff"></circle>
    </svg>
</div>
```